# Displaying date from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to get one and only the first value from a date column in my database, and put it in my PHP file, this is the snippet of the code to get the date:

```
            $one = 1;
            $Lihat="SELECT * FROM event where status = '$one'";
            $Tampil = mysqli_query($db, $Lihat);
            while ( $hasil = mysqli_fetch_array ($Tampil)) {
                    $query_start_date = "SELECT tgl_event
                                    FROM jadwal_acara
                                    WHERE id_event = '$id_event' AND status = $one
                                    ORDER BY tgl_event ASC
                                    LIMIT 1";

                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query_start_date);
                $start_date = mysqli_fetch_field($result);

     <td class="tgl_mulai"><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($start_date));?></td>
```

The problem is that when i tried to echo it in my table row:

It returns an error that said:

```
strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.
```

Does anyone know how to change it into a string or another method to get the desired display result? Thank you.

EDIT:

$start_date = var_dump($start_date); returns a NULL value when i tested it.

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$tgl_event in
NULL

But i got other rows that displayed the correct name and event ID, it's just the date that won't display correctly.

it now displays :01-01-1970

Comment: var_dump $start_date and print the output

Comment: $start_date = var_dump($start_date); returns a NULL value when i tested it.

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$tgl_event in
NULL

But i got other rows that displayed the correct name and event ID, it's just the date that won't display correctly.

it now displays :01-01-1970

Comment: Always check for errors and empty result sets after using `mysqli_query()`

Comment: I've added the if and else to check the errors for the query, it doesn't return an error for the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**mysqli_fetch_field()**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) returns an object. Instead use [**mysqli_fetch_assoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Try this:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT tgl_event FROM jadwal_acara WHERE id_event = ".$id_event." AND status = 1 ORDER BY tgl_event ASC LIMIT 1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
    while ($finfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($finfo['tgl_event']));
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($db);
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<td class="tgl_mulai"><?php echo $date; ?></td>
```

Comment: I got this error:

Undefined property: stdClass::$tgl_event in...

and the date is now displayed, but the result is always :01-01-1970, but the other rows that has the name and event id values are displayed correctly, do you know why?

Comment: Hmm can I see how you're storing the date in the field?

Comment: this is inside a foreach to store the data:

$post_insert_tgl_event = $db->real_escape_string($value);

because what i am trying to make is a web for an event and its sessions, and i want to get only the earliest date for the sessions in one event

this is the structure of the table

name: tgl_event
type: date
null: no
default: none

The dates does exist on the tables, it's just that the problem is displaying them.